# How do I get my self hosted fonts to work?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, self-hosting

I'm trying self hosted fonts for the first time, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

https://treasure.studiothensome.com/home-2/

```
    font-family: mercury-display-roman; 
    src: url('http://www.treasure.studiothensome.com/wp-content/themes/treasure/fonts/MercuryDisplay-Roman_Web.woff');  
    font-weight: normal;  
}
@font-face {
    font-family: Fakt-Blond; 
    src: url('http://www.treasure.studiothensome.com/wp-content/themes/treasure/fonts/Fakt-Blond.woff');  
    font-weight: normal;  
}
```

Comment: you are hosting the site on `https` but the fonts URLs are using `http` to reach the fonts - can you confirm if this is or isn't a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `https`

> If your website delivers HTTPS pages, all active mixed content
>   delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default.
>   Consequently, your website may appear broken to users (if iframes or
>   plugins don't load, etc.). Passive mixed content is displayed by
>   default, but users can set a preference to block this type of content,
>   as well.

Then change the `font-family` from

```
  font-family: Fakt-Blond;
```

to

```
  font-family: 'Fakt-Blond';
```

do the same for `mercury-display-roman`

but you shall use it this way

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fakt-Blond';
    src: url('wp-content/themes/treasure/fonts/Fakt-Blond.woff');
    font-weight: normal; 
}
```

if you open the [chrome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) under `Network` you will see this

[image]

Reading: [How to fix a website with blocked mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content)

Comment: okay, thanks for your help! 

Here's what I did, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

```@font-face {
    font-family: 'mercury-display-roman'; 
    src: url('https://www.treasure.studiothensome.com/wp-content/themes/treasure/fonts/MercuryDisplay-Roman_Web.woff');  
    font-weight: normal;  
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Fakt-Blond'; 
    src: url('https://www.treasure.studiothensome.com/wp-content/themes/treasure/fonts/Fakt-Blond.woff');  
    font-weight: normal;  
}

Comment: try to change the source like this `src: url('wp-content/themes/treasure/fonts/Fakt-Blond.woff');`

Comment: AMAZING! 

Thanks so much for your help!